# ImageMagick の blur 処理について

Tags: imagemagick, 画像処理

[-blur radius](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php)

Q1.ラジウスと(オプションとして)シグマ値を指定するようですが、それぞれどういう値ですか？ 画像をぼかすことにどう影響するのですか？
(引数の数値を、試しに色々変更してみましたが、どう関係しているのか分かりませんでした。)

> -blur radius{xsigma}

Q2.下記はどういう意味ですか？

> Radius should be at least twice the Sigma value, though three times
> will produce a more accurate result.

↓ 自動翻訳

> 目安として、Radiusはシグマ値の2倍以上であるべきですが、3倍であればより正確な結果が得られます。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

なぜ？と問われると純粋数学の問題になっちゃいます。 ImageMagick の blur はガウス関数で計算を行うので、シグマ値＝標準偏差値のほうが本質です。 [ガウシアンぼかし](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%AC%E3%82%A6%E3%82%B7%E3%82%A2%E3%83%B3%E3%81%BC%E3%81%8B%E3%81%97) (Wikipedia) では標準偏差値のみ用いて違いを表記していますよね。また php の `Imagick::motionBlurImage` 関数の[php 公式解説](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/imagick.motionblurimage.php)においても [半径に `0` を指定すると適切な値を計算で求めます] とあります。

ではガウス関数（ガウシアン）って何とか、標準偏差って何とか、これをどう適用したらボケ（ぼかし）になるのかってあたりは純粋数学なのでオイラでは説明できる自信がないです。そもそもぼかしって何あたりから始める必要がありそうで長くなりますし。

この質問に対する回答としては
- シグマ値とはガウシアンの標準偏差値のことである
- 半径値とは、今演算しようとしている注目点の周囲何ドットを演算に含めるか
としか言いようがなくてこれは先の php マニュアルと同じ文言(質問文そのものと同じ) になっちゃいます。

シグマ値を大きくするとどう変わるかは Wikipedia の画像とかを参照。むっちゃ変わっていると言っていいでしょう。

それでもあえて一言で言うと
- シグマ値を大きくする＝よりボケる
- 半径が小さすぎるとボケ演算として不適切な挙動になる
- 半径を大きくすると演算量が増えて遅くなる
のでどちらも適切な数値を指定しないと意味ないよ、適切ってのは操作する人の恣意で決めるものなので操作員（あなた）にお任せします、ってことかと。

---

標準偏差の２倍ってのは `2σ` ３倍は `3σ` ってことで[標準偏差](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%A8%99%E6%BA%96%E5%81%8F%E5%B7%AE)の図からどのくらいの広がりかは見て取れるでしょう。狭い範囲から周囲の色を拾ってきても類似した色である確率が高くて「ぼかし」になりにくいって事っス。`3σ` より広く取ってもほぼ無意味なのなんとなく納得できると思います。
# カイゼンでいうシックスシグマ `6σ` もここから来てる。

Comment: 「シグマ値の2倍以上であるべきですが、3倍であればより正確な結果」というのは、ImageMagick 固有の設定範囲というよりも、一般的な設定範囲という感じだと理解しました

Comment: ガウシアン＝正規分布、なわけです。注目点は正規分布の頂点に相当し、これをぼかすのに標準偏差より狭い領域だけ拾ってきて混ぜ合わせても頂点と類似性（色っスね）が高い周囲のドットとのみ混ぜるわけで効果が薄いってことです。この混ぜる範囲が「半径」だけど、広く取りすぎると計算量が増えてうんぬん。